iOS - Image is not visible on branch.io dynamic links
I am trying to create a dynamic link with branch io. everything is working fine the dynamic link is created successfully but the thumbnail image is not visible on the link even after adding the image url in BranchUniversalObject.
here is the code that i am using for creating dynamic link-
    private func generateShareProductDynamicLinkeURL() {
        let buo: BranchUniversalObject = BranchUniversalObject()
        buo.canonicalIdentifier = "/product/\(productDetailsVM.productDetails?.id ?? "")"
        buo.title = productDetailsVM.productDetails?.name ?? ""
        buo.contentDescription = productDetailsVM.productDetails?.description
        buo.imageUrl = productDetailsVM.productDetails?.imageUrl ?? ""
        buo.contentMetadata.contentSchema = .commerceProduct
        buo.publiclyIndex = true
        buo.contentMetadata.customMetadata["shareProduct"] = productDetailsVM.productDetails?.id ?? ""
        
        let blp: BranchLinkProperties = BranchLinkProperties()
        blp.channel = "whatsapp"
        blp.feature = "Product Sharing"
        
        buo.getShortUrl(with: blp) { url, error in
            productDetailsVM.isLoading = false
            if let url = URL(string: url ?? "") {
                shareProductDetails(url)
            } else {
                print("ERROR: while creating dynamic link - \(String(describing: error))")
            }
        }
    }

The image url is not nil. i have checked it already.

This started happening to us recently after working for many years. Judging from this page it's possible that they stealthily made this no longer work unless you have a special enterprise contract.

Please note that the $og_image_url social preview feature is reserved
for paid Branch accounts with a dedicated contract. If you do not have
a paid Branch account, you will not see this feature in the Branch
Dashboard.

This FAQ page was "Updated about 1 month ago", and the other FAQ pages were updated 3 years ago.
The only way we can customize it now is by specifying a $fallback_url that already has the desired og_image_url in its metadata, which isn't always ideal.

The same thing to me. It just stopped working. I create customized links in the dashboard and this is messing things up.

As pointed out by Michael Tom, this is no longer a feature for the free tier of Branch (as of October 17, 2024).
I reached out to Branch support and this was their response:

Customers not on our Enterprise plans can no longer customize Social
Media tags when creating links. You can refer to the following article
for details: Can I change my app icon?


